# Sharing common code between multiple spring boot APIs

Tags: java, maven, microservices, pom.xml, dry

I have two spring boot REST APIs, both of them has exactly same /health endpoint, I want to extract out this endpoint into some other Java project.

I want following things:

1. When I compile any of the APIs the common module should be compiled
2. I am using docker containers to run these APIs in separate dockers. How to copy the jar file for the common code into the Dockers.

Please ignore if the question seems silly, I am not sure whether to make the common project as a module or inject that as a dependency in these two project's pom file.

Comment: Not a bad question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of maven and your build server (Jenkins, etc) and a clever pipeline. Have your common dependency as a module and whenever you kick off a build on one of your REST projects the following should happen:

- kick off the build of your common dependency as part of the pipeline (downstream job I think)
- deploy the latest version to your maven repository
- do a maven force version update for your dependency in your REST pipeline(using `mvn versions:use-latest-releases -Dincludes=groupId:artifactId`) which will update the pom of your REST module
- push the latest pom of your REST module to git

Versioning your modules becomes important if you want to manage breaking changes carefully, otherwise you can get away with SNAPSHOTS

Comment: Yes, this is definetly a job for maven! but in complex project, code reuse becomes something on which team should spend the right amount of time for thinking. Example: many times healthchecks have just one line of code: return a 200 code. But what if some dev wants to also include database connection checks? Should be a best practice to enforce or just an exception? And, for the first case, how to handle migration from the previous practice to new one updating depencencies from the healthcheck package?

Comment: I get you and maybe the question then is how common is this function? I would think one of the reasons to have a common lib is to have a shared experience across the board. In your scenario, it sounds like implementing a [HealthAggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator.html) is more appropriate. With that in place, you can implement a common `HealthIndicator` and allow each team to implement their own 'HealthIndicator`s and the HealthAggregator can combine all the checks in one output

Comment: Yes, I like the definition of "shared experience"

Answer (score 3):

Maven can accomplish this task.

> I want following things:
>
> When I compile any of the APIs the common module should be compiled

The Maven multi module pom (called also the aggregator pom) achieves that.

1) Couple the three components in terms of build

```
- api-parent (multimodule pom and parent pom also if needed)
   |
   |____ common-lib (jar)
   |____ api-foo (spring boot fat jar)
   |____ api-bar (spring boot fat jar)
```

The drawback of this approach is that the version of `common-lib` is necessarily the same for the two apis modules that use it.   But since you want to compile  the `common-lib` at each build of any api, finally that makes sense.

You can use such an approach while you want/need that the version of `common-lib`  be the same between your apis. If later it turns out that the version of `common-lib` used by your apis should differ because these don't have the same lifecycle, you can decouple them that as the following.

2) Decouple the three components in terms of build

At the same level, defines the `common-lib` project, and two apis projects and defines in each api project a dependency to `common-lib`.

```
- common-lib (jar)

- api-foo (spring boot fat jar)
   |
   |____uses___ common-lib v1 (jar)


- api-bar (spring boot fat jar)
   |
   |____uses___ common-lib v2 (jar)
```

> I am using docker containers to run these APIs in separate dockers.
>   How to copy the jar file for the common code into the Dockers.

You don't copy this library yourself. The spring boot maven plugin creates the fat jar for you that has contains all dependencies that you declared and that are needed for your micro services. So just deploy the jars created by Spring Boot on your docker containers.

Side note :

In both approaches, I think that you should define these three projects in a same SCM repository (the mono repository approach rather than the multi repository approach) because these three components are functionally coupled.  You may want to work on all of these at the same time.

Comment: Great answer david, approach 2 seems really appealing. What changes do you envision in pom.xml for api-foo and common-lib

Comment: Thanks. What changes ? Not sure to get it :)

Comment: At the moment I have added the common-lib as a dependency in api-foo's pom file like : 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: This is fine. And I suppose that it is the same thing for the other api for the moment.  And what if your issue ?